# Using Keras like TensorFlow for gpu computing

Tags: keras

I would like to know if Keras can be used as an interface to TensoFlow for only doing computation on my GPU.

I tested TF directly on my GPU. But for ML purposes, I started using Keras, including the backend. I would find it 'comfortable' to do all my stuff in Keras instead of Using two tools.

This is also a matter of curiosity.

I found some examples like this one:

http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2018/10/28/understand-batch-matrix-multiplication.html

However this example does not actually do the calculation.
It also does not get input data.
I duplicate the snippet here:
'''

```
from keras import backend as K
a = K.ones((3,4))
b = K.ones((4,5))
c = K.dot(a, b)
print(c.shape)
```

'''

I would simply like to know if I can get the result numbers from this snippet above, and how?

Thanks,

Michel

Answer (score 0):

Keras doesn't have an eager mode like Tensorflow, and it depends on models or functions with "placeholders" to receive and output data.

So, it's a little more complicated than Tensorflow to do basic calculations like this.

So, the most user friendly solution would be creating a dummy model with one `Lambda` layer. (And be careful with the first dimension that Keras will insist to understand as a batch dimension and require that input and output have the same batch size)

```
def your_function_here(inputs):

    #if you have more than one tensor for the inputs, it's a list:
    input1, input2, input3 = inputs

    #if you don't have a batch, you should probably have a first dimension = 1 and get
    input1 = input1[0]

    #do your calculations here

    #if you used the batch_size=1 workaround as above, add this dimension again:
    output = K.expand_dims(output,0)

    return output
```

Create your model:

```
inputs = Input(input_shape)
#maybe inputs2 ....

outputs = Lambda(your_function_here)(list_of_inputs)
#maybe outputs2

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

And use it to predict the result:

```
print(model.predict(input_data))
```